# MySQL Certification Practice Questions

Tags: mysql

i am wondering how should i assume what these questions are actually asking?

**part of the question**

> Clients without projects should be
>   displayed, but **projects that don't
>   have a start date and projects that
>   don't have an end date should not be
>   displayed**.

**answer**

```
mysql> SELECT
->  c.name AS CLIENT, p.name AS PROJECT,
->  p.start AS START, p.end AS END
->  FROM client AS c
->  LEFT JOIN project AS p
->  USING (cid) /* or: ON c.cid = p.cid */
->  WHERE p.start IS NOT NULL
->  AND p.end   IS NOT NULL
->  ORDER BY c.name ASC, p.start ASC
-> ;
```

i think according to the answer, the question should be phrased as "projects that dont have a start and end date" rather than "... and projects that ... " that seem to imply exclude projects that dont have a start or end date? or isit only me?

UPDATE:

```
mysql> select c.name, p.name, p.start, p.end
    -> from client c left join project p
    -> using (cid);
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| name       | name         | start      | end        |
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| Seamen's   | Intranet     | NULL       | NULL       |
| Lennart AG | New CMS      | 2003-01-00 | 2003-05-00 |
| Lennart AG | Intranet     | 2009-02-00 | NULL       |
| MySQL AB   | Texi2XML     | 2002-04-00 | 2003-09-00 |
| MySQL AB   | Study Guides | 2002-09-00 | 2003-03-30 |
| Icoaten    | PDC Server   | 2003-01-00 | 2003-01-00 |
| Icoaten    | SMB Server   | 2003-05-00 | NULL       |
| Icoaten    | WLAN         | NULL       | 2003-08-00 |
| Nittboad   | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       |
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> select c.name, p.name, p.start, p.end
    -> from client c left join project p
    -> using (cid)
    -> where p.start is not null
    -> and p.end is not null;
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| name       | name         | start      | end        |
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| Lennart AG | New CMS      | 2003-01-00 | 2003-05-00 |
| MySQL AB   | Texi2XML     | 2002-04-00 | 2003-09-00 |
| MySQL AB   | Study Guides | 2002-09-00 | 2003-03-30 |
| Icoaten    | PDC Server   | 2003-01-00 | 2003-01-00 |
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select c.name, p.name, p.start, p.end
    -> from client c left join project p
    -> using (cid)
    -> where p.start is not null
    -> or p.end is not null ;
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| name       | name         | start      | end        |
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| Lennart AG | New CMS      | 2003-01-00 | 2003-05-00 |
| Lennart AG | Intranet     | 2009-02-00 | NULL       |
| MySQL AB   | Texi2XML     | 2002-04-00 | 2003-09-00 |
| MySQL AB   | Study Guides | 2002-09-00 | 2003-03-30 |
| Icoaten    | PDC Server   | 2003-01-00 | 2003-01-00 |
| Icoaten    | SMB Server   | 2003-05-00 | NULL       |
| Icoaten    | WLAN         | NULL       | 2003-08-00 |
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**update 3:**

> "projects that don't have a start and
>   end date" is looking for both fields
>   missing, mathematically: Start IS NULL
>   AND End IS NULL.
>
> "projects that don't have a start date
>   and projects that don't have an end
>   date" is, as you say, really "OR"
>   (Start IS NULL OR End IS NULL). Note:
>   This is equivalent to "NOT (Start IS
>   NOT NULL AND End IS NOT NULL)".

Comment: certificationoverflow.com perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE p.start IS NOT NULL
AND p.end IS NOT NULL
```

excludes both cases. So projects that don't have a start date are excluded, as are projects that don't have an end date. Of course, projects with neither a start date nor an end date are excluded as well.

Their wording, at least to me, very unambiguously specifies that behavior.

Note, however, that their answer has another problem: A client with one project, but that one project has a missing start or end date (or both), will not be displayed. Oops.

---

## edit: try #2

Questions about English are heading towards offtopic, but I read that sentences as:

> Clients without projects should be displayed, but (*projects that don't
>   have a start date*) and (*projects that don't have an end date*) should not
>   be displayed.

In other words, as a two-item list. Grammatically identical to:

> Clients without projects should be displayed, but Seamen's and MySQL AB should not not be displayed.

Note that clearly means that a client shouldn't be displayed if its name is Seamen's or if its name is MySQL AB, not that it shouldn't be displayed if its name is both!

Comment: err... i updated my post, are you sure you are right? i am confused ... "So projects that don't have a start date are excluded, as are projects that don't have an end date. Of course, projects with neither a start date nor an end date are excluded as well" refers to the 3rd query where i used OR?

Comment: No, it refers the the 2nd (AND) query. Notice how the second query shows only rows where both start and end are filled in. In other words, rows that don't have a start date are not displayed and rows that don't have an end date are not displayed.

Comment: err i also posted http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,279954,279981#msg-279981 and got a different answer, something that i find more logical. see update 3